# Floor inconsistent with Less for machine-precision approximate numbers

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

For machine-precision numbers, Mathematica uses a tolerance for comparisons, so that `1.-$MachineEpsilon==1.` However, `Floor` does not take into account this tolerance, leading to an inconsistency:

```
{Floor[#], # < 1., # >= 1.} &[1. - $MachineEpsilon]
(*{0, False, True}*)
(*Should be {1,False,True} or {0,True,False}*)
```

For the particular piece of code this affects, I am using `Compile` and so can just set the `RuntimeOptions` to not `CompareWithTolerance` (which is what `Floor` assumes). However, I thought it worth asking if it is possible to avoid this in general, or is it necessary to refactor code that assumes this consistency?

For what it's worth, it also appears to be inconsistent with the documentation which states that "`Floor[x]` gives the greatest integer less than or equal to x" and the documentation gives an example of it working correctly for an arbitrary-precision number, e.g. `` Floor[1`100 - 10^-130]==1 ``

Comment: In the documentation for Less (and equal, etc.) It specifies that it does not consider the last bit in the comparison, as you're seeing here. 

Also, the example you list: ``Floor[1`100 - 10^-130]==1`` is listed under "Possible Issues", which indicates that it doesn't necessarily work as expected; this is because you're specifying a precision of 100 digits with ``1`100``, whereas `1.` is specified as `MachinePrecision`; clearly `10^-130` would require more than 130 digits of precision, and so is neglected in evaluation.

Comment: @Michael, that's almost an answer already. :) Consider writing one when you find the time.

Comment: @MichaelWitt if I understand the documentation correctly, it is the last byte that is ignored by `Less`. This doesn't particularly bother me. However, the definition of equality should be consistent throughout. The greatest integer less than or equal to `1.-$MachineEpsilon` is 1 according to `Less` and 0 according to `Floor`. It gives a bug in code such as `If[1<=x<Length[list]+1,list[[Floor[x]]],0]`. If x is `1.-$MachineEpsilon`, we get `Head[list]` rather than 0 or `list[[1]]` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is pretty much the same as the one given in [Bug in floating-point number comparisons near $MachineEpsilon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/bug-in-floating-point-number-comparisons-near-machineepsilon/170382#170382)
The OP seems familiar with the reasoning given there.

For a workaround, as explained in the linked Q&A, one can do the following to set the tolerance to zero:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
 {Floor[#], # < 1., # >= 1.} &[1. - $MachineEpsilon]
 ]
(*  {0, True, False}  *)
```

As for the second example, one can see that `` 1`100 - 10^-130 `` evaluates to `` 1.`100. ``; consequently, `Floor[]` will evaluate to `1`.

```
1`100 - 10^-130 // InputForm
(*  1.`100.  *)
```