# Bug in floating-point number comparisons near $MachineEpsilon?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

I stumbled over the following weird behavior when comparing floating-point numbers close to 1.0:

```
qq = 1.0 + 60.0 $MachineEpsilon;
```

and then

```
qq > 1.0
```

yields False. However,

```
qq - 1
```

yields

```
1.33227*10^-14
```

which is far above $MachineEpsilon = 2.22045*10^-16 (the smallest number eps satisfying (1.0 + eps > 1.0)==True when using 8-byte floating point numbers). Changing the first command to

```
qq = 1.0 + 65.0 $MachineEpsilon;
```

Leads to the expected behavior of (qq > 1.0) == True.

I'm running Mathematica 10.4.0.0 under Windows on an Intel i5.

Ron

Comment: `SetPrecision[qq, MachinePrecision] > 1`

Comment: @Feyre Still `False`.

Comment: @corey979 Sorry, should be `16` or higher, `MachinePrecision` only works with a `qq` rationalized as `qq = 1 + 60 $MachineEpsilon`, something I did without thought, first idea with precision issues is always using rational numbers.

Comment: This comes about because `Equal` is fuzzy and mutually exclusive trichotomy is enforced.

Comment: I think this "feature" deserves at least a comment in the documentation of $MachineEpsilon. There's a good section in the Help text to Equal[] under "Possible Issues".

Answer (score 5):

As said in a comment:

> This comes about because Equal is fuzzy and mutually exclusive trichotomy is enforced. – Daniel Lichtblau [Dec 6 '16 at 14:47](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/bug-in-floating-point-number-comparisons-near-machineepsilon#comment358598_132890)

Perhaps this question also deserves some suggestions for workarounds.  The tolerance is relative, so comparing with `0` effectively compares with no tolerance.

```
qq - 1.0 > 0
(*  True  *)
```

The amount of tolerance is controlled by `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``, which can be set to zero.  (For a related Q&A, see [Machine Epsilon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48810/machine-epsilon)).

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, qq > 1.0]
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on _mutually exclusive trichotomy_ please?

Comment: @anderstood The [Trichotomy Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrichotomyLaw.html) states that only one of $a < b$, $a = b$, and $a > b$ can be true.  I assume that's what Daniel means.

Comment: So could the problem come from the fact that `qq==1.` returns `True`? Is `qq - 1. == 0` $\neq$ `qq == 1.` and expected behaviour (I understand that it's a consequence from the relative tolerance).

Comment: @anderstood Yes, that's why Daniel singles out `Equal`.

Comment: Yes to what I meant by trichotomy and yes to the expected behavior and rationale.