# Why am I getting that $0.999999999999988 \geq 1.0$ is True?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I am getting these results:

```
0.999999999999988 < 1.0  (*False*)
0.999999999999988 >=  1.0  (*True*)
0.999999999999988 ===  1.0  (*False*)

Block[{$MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision, $MaxPrecision=$MachinePrecision}, 0.999999999999988 >=  1.0] (*False*)


N[0.999999999999988 -  1.0]  (*small negative number, but larger in magnitude than machine precision*)

PossibleZeroQ[N[0.999999999999988 -  1.0]]  (*False*)
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you found the work around: instead of testing `a == b`, check `a - b == 0` (same with <, >).  The normal rules of arithmetic don't necessarily apply when you're working with floating point numbers.

Comment: ```0.999999999999988`17. >= 1.`17.``` gives `False` See also `Possible Issues` in the documentation of `Equal`.

Comment: Finding that this was the source of a larger problem was a (time-consuming) surprise.  I think that including this in Possible Issues for Less  would be helpful, or perhaps an option for Less[a,b,NumericalPrecision->xxx]?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [(48810)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48810), [(132890)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132890)

Comment: Oh, I was looking in the docs at LessThan (where "Possible Issues" is absent). I see it in Less now. Thanks.

Comment: Note that while `0.999999999999988 === 1.0` gives `False`, `0.999999999999988 == 1.0` gives `True`. `===` is `SameQ`, and `==` is `Equal`; `SameQ` tests if they're literally the same expression, whereas `Equal` cooperates with `<=`. (Edit: Oops, saw this was covered in one of the not-accepted answers, but I'll leave it here for quick reference by anyone reading this.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can lower the value of [`` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdditionalFunctions/ExperimentalContext/NumericalComputation/$EqualTolerance.html):

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
  0.999999999999988 >= 1.0 
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

This can lead to unexpected behaviors too:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
  0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Maybe there's a better sweet spot that fits your needs. For these two examples, this works:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = Internal`$SameQTolerance},
  0.999999999999988 >= 1.0 
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = Internal`$SameQTolerance},
  0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If you have a nice representative sample of values you're comparing, you can estimate a value for `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` by plotting. These two examples return correct comparisons for values between `Log10[5/3]` and `Log10[108]`:

```
correctEquals[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = x}, 
    Boole[Not[0.999999999999988 >= 1.0] && (0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)]
  ]

Plot[correctEquals[x], {x, 0, Internal`$EqualTolerance}]
```

[image]

Comment: This would be a great addition to the Documentation or in a Guide. Excellent answer.

Comment: This explains why `0.999999999999988 >=  1.0` was true, but it doesn't explain why `0.999999999999988 ===  1.0` was simultaneously false.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft : "SameQ requires exact correspondence between expressions, except that it still considers Real numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit."  and `RealDigits[#, 2] & /@ {0.999999999999988, 1.0}` exhibits discrepancy long before the last binary digit.  If you meant `0.999999999999988 == 1.0`, at least on M'ma 11.3, this gives `True`.

Comment: Any insight as to why the values that work in this case are exactly `Log10[5/3]` and `Log10[108]` ?

Comment: Good question, I'm curious to know why too.

Comment: @Carmeister Exactly at what `Internal\`$EqualTolerance` level?

Answer (score 11):

From the help.

Equal (==):
Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits).

This explains the fist two cases: 0.999999999999988 and 1. differ by less than 7 digits.

SameQ (===):
SameQ requires exact correspondence between expressions, except that it still considers Real numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit.

As  0.999999999999988 and 1. differ by more than one digits they, are considered different.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sign[ 0.999999999999988 - 1.0]
```

> `-1`

Comment: This approach has its limitations: for example, following the documentation,  `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 10000}, 
 N[Sign[0.9999999999999999999999 - 1.0], 40]]` produces `0`.